# mongodb rs.status to list status of the node

Tags: mongodb

the moment I use sed to replace node and port the quotes are removed and hence syntax error.
Is there a different solution to this syntax error.

```
NODE=abcd
PORT=1234
mongo_cmd="mongo admin -u $USER  -p $PASWD --host $NODE --port $PORT --quiet --eval 'rs.status().members.filter( x => x.name == "NODE:PORT" ).shift().stateStr)' "
mongo_cmd=$(echo $mongo_cmd | sed -e "s/NODE/$NODE/" -e "s/PORT/$PORT/")
echo $mongo_cmd

mongo admin -u <user>  -p <pass> --host abcd --port 1234 --quiet --eval 'rs.status().members.filter( x => x.name == abcd:1234 ).shift().stateStr)'

2022-03-09T23:45:45.300-0800 E QUERY    [main] SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list @(shell eval):1:73
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe like this:

```
NODE=abcd
PORT=1234
cmd="rs.status().members.filter( x => x.name == '$NODE:$PORT' ).shift().stateStr)"
mongo_cmd="mongo admin -u '$USER'  -p '$PASWD' --host $NODE --port $PORT --quiet --eval "$cmd"
```

or

```
mongo_cmd="mongo 'mongodb://$USER:$PASWD@$NODE:$PORT/?authSource=admin' --quiet --eval "$cmd"
```

Comment: getting `-su: syntax error near unexpected token `('` error. I'm adding the outcome to question.

Comment: Maybe but quotes around user and password, see my update.

Comment: using escape character worked well `echo "mongo admin -u $USER  -p $PASWD --host $HOST --port $PORT --quiet --eval 'rs.status().members.filter( x => x.name == \"${HOST}:${PORT}\" ).shift().stateStr'"
`